# Problems redirecting http to https in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I'm working on converting a WordPress site to https, and I'm having problems doing an automatic redirect in htaccess. I can get the home page to redirect, but nothing else. I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://selfreliantschool.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And I've also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://selfreliantschool.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But neither work on anything but the home page. Here's the home page: http://selfreliantschool.com, and here's another page: http://selfreliantschool.com/christmas-gift-bootcamp/. First works, second doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up on the htaccess route and installed a plugin (Really Simple SSL) that fixed the redirect issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's your hosting situation like? Do you have access to the actual Apache configuration file? What if you put the directives in there instead of in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Check your URL in General -> Settings. If that does not work, look in your wp-config file to see if the home and siteurl are being overwritten.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

Comment: That was the first conversion step I did, switching those two settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would download your SQL file and do a find and replace for http to https

You can do this in a code editor such as Notepad++ or Sublime where you can use the shortcuts Ctrl + H

Then just drop the original SQL table and insert the edited one.

But do take a backup first - Other people may have a different solution, and only do the above if you feel confident

Comment: What does the SQL database have to do with a redirect? The content on the pages has already been converted anyway, if you access a page by explicitly typing https it shows as secure.

Comment: @BillOsuch because wordpress stores the url's in the sql files and I'm guessing this is conflicting with the htaccess redirect he's implementing. He's not actually redirecting the website he's just changing it to https, so a simple redirect won't work for what he's trying to do.

Comment: Nope, every http: instance in the db has already been changed over to https:, including the guid column of wp_posts

Comment: How have you changed every http instance?

Comment: I ask this as you have more than just the guids that need changing - The find and replace is the simplest option I've found and just saves you having to know where all the instances are that need changing.  If you are doing this via SQL query then these are the instances that need changing.  wp_options = option_value
wp_posts - guid, 
wp_posts - post_content, 
wp+postmeta - meta_value, I hope that helps but your .htaccess file doesn't seem to be the problem, and I think it is clearly something else.

Comment: I used a plugin to replace every instance, every column, case insensitive. Then double-checked via SQL query.

Comment: I've just been on the link https://selfreliantschool.com/ and and visted all the pages, and it seems to be fine when I'm visiting all the pages.  Is this not working on any particular page at your end?  It might just be the dreaded cache, that's causing you a headache

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins? If so try refreshing these, and maybe try visiting by using proxysite.com